# What does in:variable1;in:variable2; mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

A question in my ODE textbook is as follows.

> Determine whether the given first-order differential equation is linear in the indicated dependent variable.
>
> $u dv+(v+uv-e^u)du = 0;$ *in v; in u;*

I feel as though I would be able to solve the question if I knew what the *in v; in u;* means.

**In this question, what does *in v; in u;* mean? Is this a standard notation, and if so, what is it called?**

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @Darksonn thanks, question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a question about English writing.  The question could be rewritten as

> Determine whether the first-order differential equation
>   $$u dv+(v+uv-e^u)du = 0$$ is linear in $u$.  Determine also whether it is linear in $v$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation in question looks to me like a shorthand way of asking these two questions:

1. Is $u dv+(v+uv-e^u)du = 0$ linear in $u$?
2. Is $u dv+(v+uv-e^u)du = 0$ linear in $v$?

Here I'm reading the word "in" as just a word in (mathematical) English, not a mathematical notation.

Answer (score -1):

$u~dv+(v+uv-e^u)~du=0$

$u\dfrac{dv}{du}+(u+1)v-e^u=0$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}+\dfrac{u+1}{u}v=\dfrac{e^u}{u}$

$\therefore$ This is a first-order ODE with the dependent variable $v$ .